# Team Foundation Version Control - Easiest Way to Overwrite Remote Changes

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc

A co-worker of mine overwrote some my changes by mistake in good number of files in a folder (basically he had no changes in those files, just pushed older version of the files from his machine). I'm new on the project that uses TFVC. What will be the easiest way for me to overwrite those files. Some of these files have some new changes that are still on my machine and some have no new changes.
Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you not revert his changeset?

Comment: @HamidShahid He has more files in there with changes. You think it will be much easier if he resolves this by rolling back the whole changeset and then updating his local and checking in only the files he needs to ? If so , I can ask him.

Comment: I would be the best approach I would think

Comment: @HamidShahid Thank you! I asked him to do so and my issue is resolved.

Comment: @sayayin please approve my answer so that it can benefit other community members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to ask your colleague to revert his changeset.